# Multiple color fill on SVG as component in React

Tags: reactjs, svg

I can change the fill of an SVG using it as a component

```
import { ReactComponent as Icon} from '../assets/icon.svg'
...
<Icon fill='#000' />
```

With "current" on the fill field inside the SVG file

```
<path fill="current" />
```

But I have two differents path. How can I set them to have differents fills?

```
<path fill="current" />
<path fill="otherColor?" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to use different colors by creating a component that return that SVG as JSX passing colors as props

```
const Icon = ({inside, outside}) => (
  <svg>
    <g>
      <path fill={outside} />
      <path fill={inside} />
    </g>
  </svg>
)
```

```
<Icon outside='#000' inside='red'/>
```